# Upper/Downy controls for HTML

Tags: html, controls

In Windows Forms apps, you can add an upper downy control to the form. It just has a textbox with two buttons next to it, that let you  increment or decrement the value in the textbox on the left. Is there a control like that for HTML? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: There currently isn't a standard HTML control for that. Actually, that's not right. There _is_ a control for that in HTML *5* but that isn't yet supported by all browsers. When it finally will be, you'll be able to use something like this: <input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="2" value="6" />. More about this new (and other) controls in HTML 5: http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#type-number

Comment: Note: As of May, shi**y IE 9 still does not support this control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style it how you like, but you can implement it as follows...

```
<p><input type="text" name="uppydowner" id="uppydowner" value="1" size="2"> 
    <span id="uppy"></span> <span id="downy"></span></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var upButton = document.getElementById("uppy");
    var downButton = document.getElementById("downy");
    var resultBox = document.getElementById("uppydowner");

    upButton.innerHTML = "+";
    downButton.innerHTML = "-";

    upButton.onclick = function () {
        var current = parseInt(resultBox.value);
        current++;
        resultBox.value = current;
    };

    downButton.onclick = function () {
        var current = parseInt(resultBox.value);
        current--;
        resultBox.value = current;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sohnee. And yaay! You even used my uppy/downy words lol :)

Comment: I liked the sound of it so much, I've now named a jQuery plugin after it... http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Jquery-Uppy-Downer/

Answer (score 1):

It does not exist, you must build this behaviour with JavaScript.

You place a `textarea` or a `div` and use JavaScript to scroll the content up or down.

I've read about it somewhere in the past, but I can't recall where, sorry... :\

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to mimic this behaviour. I think all that would need to be done is place a textbox on there, along with an image of an up arrow and down arrow, then just change the value on the onclick event of the increment/decrement buttons/images. :) Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this control : http://www.onlinetools.org/tests/countertest.html . It is a simple javascript modification of the input control.

Comment: Thanks, Basarat. I'll check it out